# MuPDF for android

Tags: android, pdf, mupdf

G'day there!

I have a problem compilation of mupdf for android

```
Compile thumb : mupdfcore <= pdf_cmap_table.c
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:5:35: error: ../generated/cmap_cns.h: No such file or directory
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:6:34: error: ../generated/cmap_gb.h: No such file or directory
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:7:37: error: ../generated/cmap_japan.h: No such file or directory
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:8:37: error: ../generated/cmap_korea.h: No such file or directory
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:14: error: 'cmap_78_EUC_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:15: error: 'cmap_78_EUC_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:16: error: 'cmap_78_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:17: error: 'cmap_78_RKSJ_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:18: error: 'cmap_78_RKSJ_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:19: error: 'cmap_78_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:20: error: 'cmap_78ms_RKSJ_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:21: error: 'cmap_78ms_RKSJ_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:22: error: 'cmap_83pv_RKSJ_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:23: error: 'cmap_90ms_RKSJ_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:24: error: 'cmap_90ms_RKSJ_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:25: error: 'cmap_90msp_RKSJ_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:26: error: 'cmap_90msp_RKSJ_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:27: error: 'cmap_90pv_RKSJ_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:28: error: 'cmap_90pv_RKSJ_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:29: error: 'cmap_Add_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:30: error: 'cmap_Add_RKSJ_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:31: error: 'cmap_Add_RKSJ_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:32: error: 'cmap_Add_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:33: error: 'cmap_Adobe_CNS1_0' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:34: error: 'cmap_Adobe_CNS1_1' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:35: error: 'cmap_Adobe_CNS1_2' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:36: error: 'cmap_Adobe_CNS1_3' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:37: error: 'cmap_Adobe_CNS1_4' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:38: error: 'cmap_Adobe_CNS1_5' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:39: error: 'cmap_Adobe_CNS1_6' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:40: error: 'cmap_Adobe_CNS1_UCS2' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:41: error: 'cmap_Adobe_GB1_0' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:42: error: 'cmap_Adobe_GB1_1' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:43: error: 'cmap_Adobe_GB1_2' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:44: error: 'cmap_Adobe_GB1_3' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:45: error: 'cmap_Adobe_GB1_4' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:46: error: 'cmap_Adobe_GB1_5' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:47: error: 'cmap_Adobe_GB1_UCS2' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:48: error: 'cmap_Adobe_Japan1_0' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:49: error: 'cmap_Adobe_Japan1_1' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:50: error: 'cmap_Adobe_Japan1_2' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:51: error: 'cmap_Adobe_Japan1_3' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:52: error: 'cmap_Adobe_Japan1_4' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:53: error: 'cmap_Adobe_Japan1_5' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:54: error: 'cmap_Adobe_Japan1_6' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:55: error: 'cmap_Adobe_Japan1_UCS2' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:56: error: 'cmap_Adobe_Japan2_0' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:57: error: 'cmap_Adobe_Korea1_0' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:58: error: 'cmap_Adobe_Korea1_1' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:59: error: 'cmap_Adobe_Korea1_2' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:60: error: 'cmap_Adobe_Korea1_UCS2' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:61: error: 'cmap_B5_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:62: error: 'cmap_B5_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:63: error: 'cmap_B5pc_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:64: error: 'cmap_B5pc_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:65: error: 'cmap_CNS_EUC_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:66: error: 'cmap_CNS_EUC_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:67: error: 'cmap_CNS1_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:68: error: 'cmap_CNS1_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:69: error: 'cmap_CNS2_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:70: error: 'cmap_CNS2_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:71: error: 'cmap_ETHK_B5_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:72: error: 'cmap_ETHK_B5_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:73: error: 'cmap_ETen_B5_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:74: error: 'cmap_ETen_B5_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:75: error: 'cmap_ETenms_B5_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:76: error: 'cmap_ETenms_B5_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:77: error: 'cmap_EUC_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:78: error: 'cmap_EUC_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:79: error: 'cmap_Ext_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:80: error: 'cmap_Ext_RKSJ_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:81: error: 'cmap_Ext_RKSJ_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:82: error: 'cmap_Ext_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:83: error: 'cmap_GB_EUC_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:84: error: 'cmap_GB_EUC_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:85: error: 'cmap_GB_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:86: error: 'cmap_GB_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:87: error: 'cmap_GBK_EUC_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:88: error: 'cmap_GBK_EUC_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:89: error: 'cmap_GBK2K_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:90: error: 'cmap_GBK2K_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:91: error: 'cmap_GBKp_EUC_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:92: error: 'cmap_GBKp_EUC_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:93: error: 'cmap_GBT_EUC_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:94: error: 'cmap_GBT_EUC_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:95: error: 'cmap_GBT_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:96: error: 'cmap_GBT_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:97: error: 'cmap_GBTpc_EUC_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:98: error: 'cmap_GBTpc_EUC_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:99: error: 'cmap_GBpc_EUC_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:100: error: 'cmap_GBpc_EUC_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:101: error: 'cmap_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:102: error: 'cmap_HKdla_B5_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:103: error: 'cmap_HKdla_B5_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:104: error: 'cmap_HKdlb_B5_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:105: error: 'cmap_HKdlb_B5_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:106: error: 'cmap_HKgccs_B5_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:107: error: 'cmap_HKgccs_B5_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:108: error: 'cmap_HKm314_B5_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:109: error: 'cmap_HKm314_B5_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:110: error: 'cmap_HKm471_B5_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:111: error: 'cmap_HKm471_B5_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:112: error: 'cmap_HKscs_B5_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:113: error: 'cmap_HKscs_B5_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:114: error: 'cmap_Hankaku' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:115: error: 'cmap_Hiragana' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:116: error: 'cmap_Hojo_EUC_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:117: error: 'cmap_Hojo_EUC_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:118: error: 'cmap_Hojo_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:119: error: 'cmap_Hojo_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:120: error: 'cmap_KSC_EUC_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:121: error: 'cmap_KSC_EUC_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:122: error: 'cmap_KSC_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:123: error: 'cmap_KSC_Johab_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:124: error: 'cmap_KSC_Johab_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:125: error: 'cmap_KSC_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:126: error: 'cmap_KSCms_UHC_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:127: error: 'cmap_KSCms_UHC_HW_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:128: error: 'cmap_KSCms_UHC_HW_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:129: error: 'cmap_KSCms_UHC_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:130: error: 'cmap_KSCpc_EUC_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:131: error: 'cmap_KSCpc_EUC_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:132: error: 'cmap_Katakana' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:133: error: 'cmap_NWP_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:134: error: 'cmap_NWP_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:135: error: 'cmap_RKSJ_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:136: error: 'cmap_RKSJ_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:137: error: 'cmap_Roman' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:138: error: 'cmap_UniCNS_UCS2_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:139: error: 'cmap_UniCNS_UCS2_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:140: error: 'cmap_UniCNS_UTF16_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:141: error: 'cmap_UniCNS_UTF16_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:142: error: 'cmap_UniGB_UCS2_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:143: error: 'cmap_UniGB_UCS2_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:144: error: 'cmap_UniGB_UTF16_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:145: error: 'cmap_UniGB_UTF16_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:146: error: 'cmap_UniHojo_UCS2_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:147: error: 'cmap_UniHojo_UCS2_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:148: error: 'cmap_UniHojo_UTF16_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:149: error: 'cmap_UniHojo_UTF16_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:150: error: 'cmap_UniJIS_UCS2_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:151: error: 'cmap_UniJIS_UCS2_HW_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:152: error: 'cmap_UniJIS_UCS2_HW_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:153: error: 'cmap_UniJIS_UCS2_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:154: error: 'cmap_UniJIS_UTF16_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:155: error: 'cmap_UniJIS_UTF16_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:156: error: 'cmap_UniJISPro_UCS2_HW_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:157: error: 'cmap_UniJISPro_UCS2_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:158: error: 'cmap_UniKS_UCS2_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:159: error: 'cmap_UniKS_UCS2_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:160: error: 'cmap_UniKS_UTF16_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:161: error: 'cmap_UniKS_UTF16_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:162: error: 'cmap_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:163: error: 'cmap_WP_Symbol' undeclared here (not in a function)
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/mupdfcore/__/__/pdf/pdf_cmap_table.o] Error 1
```

As I can see a problem in generated directory with header files doesn't exist. How could it be? I install latest verstion of mupdf for git repository (1.0+) and mupdf thirdparty too.

Please, could you help me?

PS. Thanks for help.

Comment: Are you read pdf file using mupdf? Right?

Comment: I wanna read pdf file by means mupdf, but I need to build its before.

Comment: I have one Example for read pdf from sdcard using PDFViewer.jar file, if u want then i will give you.

Comment: Thanks alot, but I wanna built native library for x86....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read android/ReadMe.txt, you'll see step by step instructions on how to build for Android. Step 11 (quoted below) clearly describes what you need to do:

> 11) Finally, you will need a copy of a 'generated' directory. This is not
>   currently available to download.
>
> The normal mupdf build process involves running some code on the host
>   (the machine on which you are compiling), rather than the target (the
>   machine/device on which you eventually want to run mupdf). This code
>   repacks various bits of information (fonts, CMAPs etc) into a more
>   compact and usable form.
>
> Unfortunately, the android SDK does not provide a compiler for the host
>   machine, so we cannot run this step automatically as part of the android
>   build. You will need to generate it by running a different build, such
>   as the windows or linux native builds.
>
> We do not make a snapshot of the generated directory available to
>   download as the contents of this directory change frequently, and we'd
>   have to keep multiple versions on the website. We assume that anyone
>   capable of building for android is capable of doing a normal hosted
>   build.
>
> On windows (where you are using cygwin), or on linux/macos, this can be
>   as simple as running 'make' in the top level directory. Even if the
>   make process fails, it should get far enough to generate you the required
>   'generated' directory, and you can continue through these instructions.

You have not followed this step, hence you don't have the required files within your 'generated' directory.

Comment: Thanks alot, mate! After several hours of building droidpdf I've missed this step =(

Comment: I stuck on same issue. I created "generated" under the "android" folder. Still I am facing the same issue.. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You just need to go root src dir (cd ../android), after run ./configure && make. After make will give you error message (don't worry about that) and you'll see generated folder =)